# How to represent information of lab panel and/or lab items in DiagnosticOrder and DiagnosticReport FHIR resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Situation (I): A practitioner orders a lab panel with multiple lab items.

Lab panel name: LP1

Lab items within LP1: LP1_A, LP1_B

DiagnosticOrder.item.code will be used to represent LP1, LP1_A and LP1_B. Is this correct?

If this is correct, such a representation is a flat list. How to use DiagnosticOrder FHIR resource to represent lab panel and lab items hierarchy?

---

Situation (I_cont): The practitioner receives a lab report a few days after his/her lab order, as shown in Situation (I).

DiagnosticReport.name will be used to represent LP1 while DiagnosticReport.result.code will be used to represent LP1_A and LP1_B. Is this correct?

---

Situation (II): A practitioner orders multiple lab items.

Lab items: L_A, L_B, L_C

DiagnosticOrder.item.code will be used to represent L_A, L_B and L_C. Is this correct?

---

Situation (II_cont): The practitioner receives a lab report a few days after his/her lab order, as shown in Situation (II).

The practitioner should receive 3 separate lab reports with DiagnosticReport.name = L_A, L_B, L_C respectively?

If not, how to represent the results of L_A, L_B and L_C in 1 single DiagnosticReport FHIR resource?

Answer (score 1):

> DiagnosticOrder.item.code will be used to represent LP1, LP1_A and LP1_B.

I don't think it's correct. In all the ordering I've seen, the panel is just specified as LP1 in the order, and LP1_A, LP1_B are not ordered explicitly.

> DiagnosticReport.name will be used to represent LP1 while DiagnosticReport.result.code will be used to represent LP1_A and LP1_B.

yes. Though note that there's a complex relationship between what is ordered and what is reported in some cases.

> DiagnosticOrder.item.code will be used to represent L_A, L_B and L_C. Is this correct?

yes

> The practitioner should receive 3 separate lab reports with DiagnosticReport.name = L_A, L_B, L_C respectively?

not so. typically a lab would gather them into groups on it's own grounds. There's a very complex relationship indeed between what a lab is asked for and what it reports. (This is a business reality, not a product of the interoperability format)

The take home is that relationship between order and report is very complex. A single order my result in multiple reports of vice versa - it's a many to many relationship, and there may be no traceability between them, unless the order and the lab itself come to specific agreements.

Comment: How would I represent this same case in the current FHIR STU3? and which would be the correct way for a lab to share the panels they accept related to the tests, something like the Master Files in HL7 v2.x? Maybe I should create a new question :)